# Video playback in HTML/JS AIR app

Tags: javascript, video, air

Is it possible to play H.264 HD video in an HTML/Javascript (no Flash) AIR app with hardware acceleration support? I can't seem to find any resources or tutorials.

I've been able to play FLVs using the AIR Javascript API, but with mediocre performance; and I'd rather use H.264 anyway.

Thanks,
Wayne

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken (I'm having similar problems), AIR simply doesn't support the  tag.

Comment: Thanks. If you're talking about the <video> tag, you're right, it's not supported. I was hoping the AIR environment would support the StageVideo object without using a SWF, but it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah.  I was hoping the same thing earlier today.  I recently developed a web app which uses jPlayer.  Client now wants the same thing as a desktop AIR app.  There is a bug in jPlayer which requires an absolute file path to the media for flash fallback to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the netstream class and mp4 video files

Comment: Can you at least provide a link to "any resources or tutorials"?